# Plot separate years on a common day-month scale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I want to create a time series plot of temperatures for the summers of 2012 and 2013.

The only problem is that I want the data series to plot one on top of the other so they can be easily compared instead of sequentially along the date axis.

```
temp <- c(22, 22, 26, 23, 18, 20, 18, 17)
date <- as.Date(c("2012-06-01", "2012-07-01","2012-08-01","2012-09-01","2013-06-01","2013-07-01","2013-08-01","2013-09-01"))
year <- as.factor(c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012","2013", "2013","2013","2013"))

df<- data.frame(temp, date, year)
```

Here's what I have so far using `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(date, temp, color=year))+
  geom_point()
```

The graph doesn't need to have the full dates listed on they x axis, in fact, it should probably just have month and day and that might solve the problem, i.e.

```
df$dayMo <- c("07-01", "07-02","07-03","07-04","07-01","07-02","07-03","07-04")
```

I didn't see a way to get `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct` (`strptime`) to allow this day-month format.

I'm also open to some other creative way of getting this done.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d")). It sets the plotting margins, but I don't think it allows you to ignore the year in the date data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your base dataset is temp and date, then this avoids manipulating the original data frame:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=strftime(date,format="%m-%d"),
                 y=temp, 
                 color=strftime(date,format="%Y")), size=3)+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Year")+
  labs(x="date")
```

[image]

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment).

So this combines the approach above with Henrik's, using dates instead of char for the x-axis, and avoiding modification of the original df.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=as.Date(paste(2014,strftime(date,format="%m-%d"),sep="-")),
                 y=temp, 
                 color=strftime(date,format="%Y")), size=3)+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Year")+
  labs(x="date")
```

[image]

Comment: So, since I have a lot of dates and times, the labels on my x axis get all jumbled and I can't see anything.  How can I use "scale_x" to see a label for just the beginning of each month, for example?

Comment: @user3347426, you may have a look at my answer with `scale_x_date`. With `Date`s on the x axis, instead of characters, it is easy to control breaks and labels.

Comment: Thanks to both jlhoward and @Henrik for this combined solution.

Comment: you should use 2012 or another leap year in the `x=` call, just in case you have a feb 29

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to create a fake date where a single year is concatenated with month and day from the original 'date'. An x variable of class `Date` is easy to format with `scale_x_date`. Load `scales` package to access nice breaks and formatting functions: `labels = date_format()`; `breaks = date_breaks()`. See `strptime` for other date formats.

```
library(scales)

df$date2 <- as.Date(paste(2014, format(date, "%m-%d"), sep = "-"))

ggplot(df, aes(date2, temp, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d"))

ggplot(df, aes(date2, temp, color=year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%d"),
               breaks = date_breaks("months"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot both years in the same plot above each other then use `dayMo` as your x values (they don't have to be `date` object).

```
df$dayMo<-c("06-01", "07-01","08-01","09-01","06-01", "07-01","08-01","09-01")
ggplot(df, aes(dayMo, temp, color=year))+
  geom_point()
```