# how to simply plot similar dates of different years in one plot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, lubridate

I have a dataframe with dates. Here are the first 3 rows with `dput`:

```
df.cv <- structure(list(ds = structure(c(1448064000, 1448150400, 1448236800
  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), y = c(10.4885204292416, 
  10.456538985014, 10.4264986311659), yhat = c(10.4851491194439, 
  10.282089547027, 10.4354960430083), yhat_lower = c(10.4169914076864, 
  10.2162549984153, 10.368531352493), yhat_upper = c(10.5506038959764, 
  10.3556867861042, 10.5093092789713), cutoff = structure(c(1447977600, 
  1447977600, 1447977600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")),.Names = c("ds", 
  "y", "yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper", "cutoff"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -3L), class = c("`enter code here`tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm trying to plot the data with `ggplot + geom_line` from similar day/month combinations in one plot. So, for example, I want the y-value of 2016-01-01 to appear on the same x-value as 2017-01-01. If found a way to do this, but it seems to be a very complex workaround:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

p <- df.cv %>% 
  mutate(jaar = as.factor(year(ds))) %>% 
  mutate(x = as_date(as.POSIXct(
    ifelse(jaar==2016, ds + years(1), ds),
                     origin = "1970-01-01")))
ggplot(p %>% filter(jaar!=2015), aes(x=x, group=jaar, color=jaar)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y))
```

It works, but as you can see I first have to extract the year, then use an `ifelse` to add one year to only the 2016 dates, convert with `POSIXct` because `ifelse` strips the class, convert back into `POSIXct` while supplying an `origin`, and finally remove the timestamp with `as_date`.

Isn't there a simpler, more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Some other alternatives: [Synchronous X-Axis For Multiple Years of Sales with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832776/synchronous-x-axis-for-multiple-years-of-sales-with-ggplot), [Plot separate years on a common day-month scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136598/plot-separate-years-on-a-common-day-month-scale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `year<-` to replace the year with any fixed leap year:

```
p <- df.cv %>% 
           mutate(jaar = as.factor(year(ds)), 
                  x = `year<-`(as_date(ds), 2000))

ggplot(p, aes(x = x, y = y, color = jaar)) + 
           geom_line()
```

Comment: ah, great! I saw the ```year <-``` syntax, but wasn't able to find out how to incorporate that into the pipes. I knew there had to be a simpler way :) Backquoting does the trick, apparently. And, adding the leapyear with ```as_date```, that is a neat trick as well :)